# How to set the coordinates for a polygon

Tags: vb.net-2010

I want to set the coordinates for my figure. [image: Desired figure]
I do not understand how to set values to get the required image.

This is the user form: [image: User form]
Whenever I input values it starts with `0,0` coordinate which I don't want. Can anyone help me with my code?

```
Public Class Form1

Dim g As System.Drawing.Graphics
Dim pen1 As New System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Blue, 2)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim p(4) As System.Drawing.Point
        p(0).X = Val(AX.Text)
        p(0).Y = Val(AY.Text)
        p(1).X = Val(BX.Text)
        p(1).Y = Val(BY.Text)
        p(2).X = Val(CX.Text)
        p(2).Y = Val(CY.Text)
        p(3).X = Val(DX.Text)
        p(3).Y = Val(DY.Text)

        g = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
        g.DrawPolygon(pen1, p)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Could it be because for point `B` you put coordinates `x = 0, y = 0` in the form?

Comment: no I don't give it 0,0...evn if I set any value the line starts from 0,0 ...i just want to get the required image ... the point B can also b named as A ..but the confusion is in giving the values

Comment: are there any changes to b done in the program ?? how to understand which values to be given

Comment: is that possible to create the points first and then join it through the connectors..

Comment: is there anyone who can help me